# How to fetch already read articles into summary buffer in gnus?

Tags: emacs, gnus

While in summary buffer how can I make gnus fetching already read articles in two situations:

1. while in a thread with some articles already read (and thus not visible). I would like to complete the thread with all the articles (not only parents!) read or unread.
2. fetch last N read articles which are not visible.

Thanks a ton!

Comment: This is definitely not a programming question, so belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/). @VitoshKa: don't repost your question, it will be migrated automatically once enough people vote to migrate.

Comment: oh, sorry I was not aware of the feature.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the summary buffer, to fetch the parent, use `^` (`gnus-summary-refer-parent-article`) (also available as `<menu-bar> <Article> <Fetch parent of article>`).

To fetch the whole thread (at least the part that's still on your server), use `A T` (`gnus-summary-refer-thread`) (`<menu-bar> <Article> <Fetch current thread>`).

To fetch more articles, use `/ o` (`gnus-summary-insert-old-articles`) (also available as `<menu-bar> <Gnus> <See old articles>`).

Comment: Oh, thanks. It was exactly what I needed.  A good lesson to look into menus for the feature. I was completely ignoring them; such a bad habit:)

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, try

```
(setq gnus-fetch-old-headers 'some)
```

in your `.gnus`

for the second, when you select the group, it should ask you how many old articles you want to fetch. Does that not work?

Comment: I needed those actions after entering the summary buffer. Gilles pointed out the solution. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun codefalling/gnus-show-all ()
  "Show all mail"
  (interactive)
  (gnus-summary-insert-old-articles t) ;; show all, or t->50 to show 50 old mail
  (goto-char (point-min)))

(add-hook 'gnus-summary-mode-hook '(lambda () (run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil 'codefalling/gnus-show-all)))
```

Then gnus will show all mail read or unread.

Comment: You have a more elegant way to do so: `(add-hook 'gnus-summary-prepared-hook 'gnus-summary-insert-old-articles)`.      Because "run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil" is the necessary time for the relevant functions to load, and `gnus-summary-prepared-hook` is exactly the hook to indicate that this task is done. After that, `gnus-summary-insert-old-articles` would not show the wrong number-p error.

Answer (score 1):

While `^` and `/ o` commands already mentioned this one useful for debugging: `M-^` (`gnus-summary-refer-article`) when you work with message pain text (which you can get by `C-u g`).

`gnus-summary-refer-parent-article` internally used `gnus-summary-refer-article`...